# Can you use 2+ hacker arrays on the same resource simultaneously?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

Can you build multiple hacker arrays and then for example, jack up the price of food on both of them at the same time? There-by potentially doubling the price increase?

I recently learned you can make use of two optimization centers and was wondering the same thing about hacker arrays, as one on its down doesn't seem that useful to mean (in terms of opportunity cost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Nope]

As you can see in the screenshot above. If both requests are for the same resource the 2nd request will be queued instead of being sent to the 2nd hacker array. If the 2nd request is for a different resource (e.g. Chemicals) it will start on the 2nd hacker array immediately.